# Confused about CURLOPT_HTTPGET and CURLOPT_POST options

Tags: php, curl

I'm confused about why there are two options related to setting the request type. They seem redundant to me. From [the PHP manual page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) for `curl_setopt()`:

CURLOPT_POST

> TRUE to do a regular HTTP POST. This POST is the normal application/x-www-form-urlencoded kind, most commonly used by HTML forms.

CURLOPT_HTTPGET

> TRUE to reset the HTTP request method to GET. Since GET is the default, this is only necessary if the request method has been changed.

If I'm understanding this correctly, by default cURL makes GET requests, but the request type can be changed to POST by doing:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

However, to change back to GET requests, in addition to doing this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false);
```

You also have to do this?

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true);
```

Comment: I would say that you do not need to actually call curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, false); Did you give it a try ? I mean, curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, true); should be enough.

Comment: Two options? There are several more options that set (other) HTTP methods! CURLOPT_UPLOAD and CURLOPT_NOBODY for example. So, there's no "opposite" of a POST (or any other kind of) request...

Comment: @DanielStenberg I thought maybe I was missing something, because it seems like to change back to `GET` you would logically just set `_POST` to 0.

Comment: With many different methods, there's no "change back" to something, you only change _to_ a method. To change _to_ GET from a previous other method you use CURLOPT_HTTPGET.

Answer (score 2):

You need to look at the `libcurl` [documentation](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html) for further insight into the differences between the options as they are quite subtle. The key seems to be if you're reusing the `curl` handle between requests.

[CURLOPT_HTTPGET](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPGET.html): Forces the HTTP request **to get back** to using GET, if a POST, HEAD, PUT, etc has been used **previously** using the same curl handle.

[CURLOPT_POST](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POST.html): Regular POST request using a **"Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"** header which is typically the kind used when submitting HTML forms. The header can then optionally be overriden using `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.